# What is an easy way to design MySQL Queries?

Tags: mysql

What is an easy way to design MySQL Queries?

Comment: With your keyboard? Please be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

A good GUI management system certainly helps.  Here's a couple of links to two of my favourites - both of which are available as free editions, but there's no shortage.

[SQLyog Community Edition](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/).  Very straightforward interface which does all I need 98% of the time without excess baggage getting in the way.  There's a commercial version which is quite expensive and adds a few extra useful management features.

[Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/). Well respected and somewhat more poweful that SQLyog.  There's versions of Toad for MSSQL and Oracle too.

Comment: As a long time user of SQLyog, and a developer using MySQL, I found that the best way to design queries is to type them out and test them in SQLyog then refactor them for speed and memory once results are obtained. To this day i have failed to find or use effectively point and click (drag and drop) UI (DIE MICROSOFT ACCESS DIE!!).

Comment: @Jake = broadly I would agree with you, if I'm creating queries myself more often than not I construct from scratch as text.  The big win I find for GUI tools though are if I have a really complex (8 way join +) sql query I'm looking at for the first or in a long time - picking it up and dropping it into a GUI to see the structure is often the fastest way to get to grips with it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a GUI designer, something like [MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)? Others I've heard of:

http://sqleonardo.altervista.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes the thread seems to be almost outdated, but, as noone told anythong about it, I suggest Navicat http://www.navicat.com/. 
It has a powerful query-builder and it's cross platform...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (in the end) is to actually learn to write and modify mysql queries. This can be harder for the first 50 queries you write, but after that you are glad you know mysql yourself instead of relying on GUI's

Answer (score -1):

I am using xampp for development of PHP-based sites. phpMyAdmin is the very easy drag n drop visual tool to accomplish MySQL tasks just in a matter of clicks. There is no need to write long Queries. Also, Xampp is free so there's no licensing issues.

Comment: There is no drag and drop features of phpMyAdmin -- this is a web based tool with limited functionality.

Comment: i know there is no drag n drop features i use that word for simple convoy the concept

Comment: if there's no drag n drop features.. don't say it! phpMyAdmin has zero drag and drops.. it's all basic DOM elements, nothing fancy..